# SSIS - control what prints to output window

Tags: ssis

is it possible to control what prints to the output window, in general?
specifically, i want to prevent a 'File System Task' from printing.

i am looping through files, performing some operations and, if successful, moving the file.  i use a Script Task to print the filename at the beginning of each loop (which is all i want to see, as long as there's no error), but the File System Task keeps printing:

```
Information: 0xC002F30F at MyFileTask, File System Task: Directory "C:\dir\file" was deleted.
```

thus, i want the following output:

```
Information: 0x0 at 1- Print FileName: file1
Information: 0xC002F30F at MyFileTask, File System Task: Directory "C:\dir\file1" was deleted.
Information: 0x0 at 1- Print FileName: file2
Information: 0xC002F30F at MyFileTask, File System Task: Directory "C:\dir\file2" was deleted.
Information: 0x0 at 1- Print FileName: file3
```

to appear as simply:

```
Information: 0x0 at 1- Print FileName: file1
Information: 0x0 at 1- Print FileName: file2
Information: 0x0 at 1- Print FileName: file3
```

i have tried the LoggingMode=Disabled, but to no avail.  i can't find any documentation on how to manage output

thanks,

Comment: for the life of me, I cannot get the behavior of having a file system task to indicate what it's doing. Perhaps a bit more info of how you have this configured would help? But as a general rule, no, you really can't control what hits the Output window. I don't even know that going down the path of writing your own logging provider would address this

Comment: the weirdest thing is that it's inconsistent.  it only does it about 70% of time... in the simplest case, its a File System Task, with Operation='Move Directory'.  in another case, its 'Move File' inside a loop (to move all files with the same name, regardless of extension, ie filename.shp, filename.dbf, filename.shx...).  both source and dest are provided by variables. i'm not sure what other configuation options would be of use?

Comment: You could try adding an OnInformation event handler to the File System Task. Within that event handler, find the System scoped variable boolean variable Propagate and flip that from True to False. That _should_ trap the information event from bubbling up to the output but I couldn't get a working repro of the problem to say whether it'd actually work. YMMV

Comment: i'm new to Event Handlers. but i believe i tried this, and it still prints. sometimes, not always.  created OnInformation handler in the File System Task, and set Propagate to False.

Comment: Perhaps a different question, why does this matter? Are you parsing the text of the Output window to identify what has/hasn't been processed?

Comment: no... its not necessary to the final product, and not even critical to development, just would make my life easier.  these will be big, overnight runs, and i'm printing the errors elsewhere.  but while i'm developing, and new kinds of errors i didnt think to handle keep popping up, its useful to see at a glance when there's an error.  when its file1, file2, file3, error, file4... its easy to find the errors.  these file system task msgs clutter the output, making it harder to see, at a glance, where errors are happening

Comment: If they're actual error events, you might be able to go into Project Properties, Configuration Properties, Debugging and in `CmdLineArguments` change that o `/rep E` and that *should* only report errors back. Never tried it from here, but might be worth a shot. It will eliminate any information events though so your progression messages will get wiped out